# PHP executable path in Adobe Brackets

Tags: php, macos, adobe-brackets, executable-path

I am running Adobe Brackets on a 2017 iMac (Retina - 27 inch) with macOS Monterey 12.2

I want to point the path to PHP inside of MAMP. What is the correct json format and code to do this in Bracket's brackets.json file?

I've seen this code for someone using XAMP on a PC:

```
"php": {
    "executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
}
```

I tried this in my brackets.json file:

```
"php": {
    "executablePath": “/applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/“
}
```

but apparently that is not correct JSON formatting. I've tried using the double forward slashes to no avail.

It **IS** the correct path to the PHP 7.4.21 php executable file within my MAMP directory though.

This is what is currently in my brackets.json file:

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "externalApplications": {
        "jpg": "Adobe Photoshop 2021",
        "jpeg": "Adobe Photoshop 2021",
        "png": "Adobe Photoshop 2021",
        "svg": "Brackets",
        "psd": "Adobe Photoshop 2021",
        "ai": "Adobe Photoshop 2021"
    }
   
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Dennis

Comment: You seem to have used the wrong kind of quotes around your string in the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

had exactly the same problem and for me - running a MacBook Pro with M1 Processor and Monterey and MAMP - worked the following:

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "linting.collapsed": true,
    "externalApplications": {
        "jpg": "Preview",
        "jpeg": "Preview",
        "png": "Preview",
        "svg": "inkscape",
        "psd": "gimp"
    },
    "php": {
        "executablePath": "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php"
    }
}
```